# React Native: react-native-maps. Animate active marker depending on ScrollView offset

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native-maps` and want to gradually animate scale of active and inactive markers depending on the `ScrollView` x offset. *(the below image describes it better)*

My approach is to create `new Animated.Value` for each marker and `Interpolate` `ScrollView` offset for each marker:

```
//Container
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...
      scale: [],
      opacity: []
    }
  }

componentWillReceiveProps(props) {

  if (props.places.length) {

    const scale = [];
    const opacity = [];

    props.places.forEach((xx, ii) => {

      this.state[`scale${ii}`] = new Animated.Value(0.5);
      this.state[`scale${ii}`] = this._scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange: [vw * (ii - 1), vw * ii, vw * (ii + 1)],
          outputRange: [0.5, 1, 0.5],
          extrapolate: 'clamp'
       });
      scale.push(this.state[`scale${ii}`]);

      this.state[`opacity${ii}`] = new Animated.Value(0);
      this.state[`opacity${ii}`] = this._scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange: [vw * (ii - 1), vw * ii, vw * (ii + 1)],
          outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
          extrapolate: 'clamp'
      });
      opacity.push(this.state[`opacity${ii}`]);
    });

    this.setState({
      scale,
      opacity,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PlacesMap scale={this.state.scale} opacity={this.state.opacity} />                  
      <ScrollView onScroll={this._onScroll} ... />
    )
  }

  _onScroll = Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this._scrollX }}}],
      { useNativeDriver: true }
    );




//PlacesMap
....

    render {
        return (
            <MapView.Animated>

                {   places && 
                    places.map((place, ii) => {
                        return (
                            <PlaceMarker
                              key={place.id.toString()}
                              place={place}
                              scale={scale[ii]}
                              opacity={opacity[ii]}
                            />
                        )
                     })
                 }

            </MapView.Animated>
     )}
```

Maybe there is a more elegant (performant) approach that I don't know, where I don't need to create `new Animated.Value` and `Interpolators` for each marker and with which I can get the same result?

[image]

Comment: I am working on a similar app. I was thinking about using a drawer of sorts, but would automatically pop out when the user actually selects a marker.

Comment: Sorry for digging such an old question, did you actually found a way of doing what you asked? Can you share  the full original code of the map screen?

Comment: @StathisNtonas it was the correct approach, but in the end I dropped it due to the changed design

Comment: Thanks Edgar, if you have any commit with the full code of the map screen can you create a gist and share it?